# How delete routes from memory in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.1

In my application I dynamically enter routes by Rails.application.routes.append command For example:

```
Rails.application.routes.append do
  resources :example
end
```

My problem is that I do not know how I could delete these routes. I tried using the Rails.application.reload_routes! and Rails.application.routes.clear! commands, but it does not work.

Do you have any ideas? Or is there any other way to dynamically add and delete routes?

Thanks in advance for your response!

Comment: Just remove the `resources :example` line

Comment: Some googling suggests that if you use `Rails.application.routes.draw` instead of `append`, then you should be able to call `Rails.application.reload_routes!` to revert your additions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Rails.application.routes.draw` rather than `Rails.application.routes.append` you should be able to use the reload_routes! method to clear the contents.  When you call reload after using append it is literally just reloading the routes that you have appended. If you draw the route it will never be appended to the routes object and you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply, it's partly working. Namely, when the page is refreshed, the application resets routes and does not recognize those newly added. Temporarily, in the main controller I set before_action, which runs reloading routes. I suspect this is due to any of the options in the environment configuration. I'm using development. Do you have any idea?